# mongodb single node configuration

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I am going to configure mongodb on a small number of cloud servers.

I am coming from mysql, and I remember that if I needed to change settings like RAM, etc. I would have to modify "my.cnf" file. This came useful while resizing each cloud server.

Now, how can I check or modify how much RAM or disk space the database is going to take for each node?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any built in broad stroke limitation tools or flags in mongodb per se and that is most likely because this is something you should be doing at the operating system level.

Most modern multi-user operating systems have built in ways to set quotas on disk space, etc per user so you could probably set up a mongo user and place the limits on them if you really wanted to. MongoDB works best when it has enough memory to hold the working set of data and indexes in memory and it does a good job of managing that on its own.

However, if you want to get granular you can take a look at the help output of `mongod --help`

I see the following options that you could tweak:

```
--nssize arg (=16)          .ns file size (in MB) for new databases
--quota                     limits each database to a certain number of files (8 default)
--quotaFiles arg            number of files allower per db, requires --quota
```